# Conditional Counting

Tags: excel, excel-formula, sum, conditional-statements

I am new to excel. I have searched google high and low for a solution and have come up empty so I am throwing myself to the mercy of the forum.

I am attempting to conditionally count data from an external excel report that is automatically generated.

**Sample Screenshot**

[image]

As an example, I am attempting to count ONLY the instances where column C = WHITE SUPREMACISTS and column B = G A A - AND the immediate next row of column B = 113U.

I'm not even sure if this is possible. So far, this is the best I've come up with:

```
=SUM(COUNTIFS([source.xls]Sheet1!B:B,{"113U","G A A - "},[source.xls]Sheet1!C:C,{"WHITE SUPREMACISTS "}))
```

This formula counts each instance of WHITE SUPREMACISTS, G A A -, and 113U which is not exactly what I'm looking for. I need it to only count the instances of WHITE SUPREMACISTS and G A A - when the immediate cell bellow equals 113U.

If this is possible, please help.

Answer (score 1):

Just use smaller range references than full column and offset one of the conditions' ranges by a row.

```
=COUNTIFS(C1:C999, "ws", B1:B999, "gaa", B2:B1000, "113u")
```

Be sure to maintain the same number of rows in each range.

Comment: by default it is = so you do not need to = inside the quotes?

Comment: Yes, no operation sign is required unless you wish something other than equality.

Comment: Thank you! I searched forever for this. It's amazing how fast you resolved this for me.